# Color the Max, Median and Min numbers in every column in range in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I have tried using the following formula: =C2=max($C:$C) but it doesn't work. Any help?

[Here is my spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tfPIynIqEgkiyrOw1y60bwJppxX1dNsmr2P3IP0eL0Q/edit#gid=1765826021)

Comment: select all columns and try this formula `=(C1=MAX(C:C))*(C1>0)`

Comment: Thanks that worked buy could you explain why my formula didn't work, please?

Comment: your formula also works for one column `C`, but only if you apply it to the range `C2:C` - because you specify in the formula itself that it should start with cell `C2`. and if you wanted to apply it to all columns - then you would just need to remove the **$** anchors from the formula `MAX()`. for a more detailed description of the conditional formatting possibilities you can look at [link1](https://yagisanatode.com/2019/03/02/google-sheets-conditional-formatting-with-custom-formula/) [link2](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2017/09/07/google-sheets-conditional-formatting/)

Comment: FYI if values in the dataset are even there is a high chance that MEDIAN is not in your set therefore it won't be painted

Answer (score 0):

#### [Sergey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15611153/sergey)'s [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67482499/find-the-max-median-and-min-numbers-in-every-column-in-range-in-google-sheets#comment119303738_67482499):

Select all columns and try this formula `=(C1=MAX(C:C))*(C1>0)`.

your formula also works for one column `C`, but only if you apply it to the range `C2:C` - because you specify in the formula itself that it should start with cell `C2`. and if you wanted to apply it to all columns - then you would just need to remove the $ anchors from the formula `MAX()`. for a more detailed description of the conditional formatting possibilities you can look at [link1](https://yagisanatode.com/2019/03/02/google-sheets-conditional-formatting-with-custom-formula/) [link2](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2017/09/07/google-sheets-conditional-formatting/)